# How to use Stack into CircleAvatar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to put Container color as Stack above circle avatar but the problem is that color go out the circle borer

I have the following code,

```
                IntrinsicWidth(
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  children: [
                    const CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 50,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                      height: 30,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
```

I get the following output

[image]

But I need the output looks like following

[image]

How Can I prevent my color from expanding to the circle width

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
  radius: 100,
  child: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
    child: Container(
      height: 40,
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks this is perfect , but How could i do it with the CricleAvatar Widget ?